# fopen \ fopen_s in c when compiled and run by command line

Tags: c, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to compile and run a simple program from the command line of vs 2010 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE* file;
    errno_t err;
    err = fopen_s(&file,"file.txt", "w");
    if(err != 0){
        printf("FAIL error = %d \n", err);
        return -1;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code on vs 2010 it works but when I try to compile and run in the command prompt I get an errno of 13(after the compile is done successfully).
Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Start by using e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string of the error, it will make it a tad easier to figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: Also, when you run from the command-line, are you sure that you have write-permissions for the current directory?

Comment: Try changing the access to read: `err = fopen_s(&file,"file.txt", "r");` If you don't get an error that way, then it would seem that you don't have the permission to modify that file. Might be fixable by running your command line "as administrator".

Comment: `%d` tells `printf` to expect an `int`, but `err` is an `errno_t`. This probably won't fix your problem, but you should fix it anyway. Consider using `printf("FAIL error = %lld \n", (long long int) err);`...

Answer (score 1):

if you use something like

```
printf( "%s\n", strerror(13) );
```

you would see the message: `Permission denied`  which says you can not open the file, as you were trying to do, for writing.